# Which folder contains executable's launcher file?

Tags: 12.04, filesystem

Just a small query that in which folder application launcher is stored.

Like when i typed

```
whereis everpad
```

[image: terminal]

it gave me multiple locations but when i checked for launcher it was no where to be seen.

Comment: Not an answer, but it may be helpful. Filesystem conventions can be checked [here](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard).

Comment: Type: which everpad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you are using Ubuntu 12.04, right?
Look in to the folder mentioned below.

```
/usr/share/applications
```

I am sure you should find your applications there. Double-click on icons to start the applications.

Comment: Great job. Yes i am using 12.04 ubuntu. And launcher is there. Thanks

Comment: One more thing When i added to startup applications it didn't work.   In Nautilus it shows all files with .desktop extension.

Comment: I am not sure how to solve this problem, but you could search for the solution on this website itself. If you can't find it, post another question. :D